# Mutate within nested data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I would like to perform `kmeans` within groups and add to my data information about cluster number and center which an observation was assigned to (still, within groups so cluster 1 is not the same for group A and group B). I thought that I can `pluck` cluster assignment and centroid from `kmeans` and then maybe join these two with each other and finally, with original data. To do the former I wanted to add a row number to data frames with centers and then join by the number of cluster. But how can I add row number within nested data frames? The following code works well until the last, 'nested' `mutate`.

```
my_data <- data.frame(group = c(sample(c('A', 'B', 'C'), 20, replace = TRUE)), x = runif(100, 0, 10), y = runif(100, 0, 10))
my_data %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(km_cluster = map(data, ~kmeans(.x, 3) %>% pluck('cluster')),
         km_centers = map(data, ~kmeans(.x, 3) %>% pluck('centers') %>% mutate(cluster = row_number())))
```

@Luke.sonnet provided an answer that works well with `map`, but interestingly not  with `map2`, see below:

```
my_data %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(number = sample(3:7, 3)) %>% 
  mutate(km_cluster = map2(data, number, ~kmeans(.x, .y) %>% pluck('cluster')), 
     km_centers = map2(data, number, ~kmeans(.x, .y) %>% pluck('centers') %>% as_tibble() %>% mutate(cluster = row_number())))
```

Any ideas how to solve the issue in that case? And equally important, what is the cause of such behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `pluck()` is returning a matrix. Cast to a tibble first and number differently.

```
library(tidyverse)
my_data <- data.frame(group = c(sample(c('A', 'B', 'C'), 20, replace = TRUE)), x = runif(100, 0, 10), y = runif(100, 0, 10))
my_data %>% 
    group_by(group) %>% 
    nest() %>% 
    mutate(number = sample(3:7, 3)) %>% 
    mutate(km_cluster = map2(data, number, ~kmeans(.x, .y) %>% pluck('cluster')), 
           km_centers = map2(data, number, ~kmeans(.x, .y) %>% pluck('centers') %>% as_tibble() %>% mutate(cluster = seq_len(nrow(.)))))
```

Note you can also do `mutate(cluster = row_number(x))))` and this provides different numbers (note that just using `row_number()` uses the rows from the parent df). I think given `kmeans` that the matrix of centers is ordered row-wise by cluster number that the answer in the main chunk is correct.

Comment: Thanks. Works well with `map` and equal number of clusters within each group, but doesn't generalise for different number of clusters and `map2` usage. I have edited my post.

Comment: Edited to accommodate this problem. Original solution only worked bc n clusters = n groups.